# Moving HTML with jQuery makes chart.js charts dissapear, no errors, unknown reason How can I redraw it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js, bootstrapping

I have a page with several Chart.js charts. The page has two views: TABULATED (bootstrap) and SEQUENTIAL. Then, when the page loads, organizes the charts into the tabulated view automatically (each tab is for each chart). The sequential html structure is:

```
<div class="chartsCotainter">
  <div class="chart1">
     <!-- here is the chart 1 ... -->
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

The problem is when the charts is finally organized disappears strangely. The solution I found to solve the problem is to organize the charts in the tabs after 5 seconds using setTimeout

```
function refreshView()
{
    console.log("Refreshing...");
    organizeChartsInTabs();
}

setTimeout( refreshView, 5000 );
```

I don't want to use `setTimeout`, I believe that is necessary to `redraw` all the charts after organize it, I don't know how. I tryed `.update()` but no success.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no complete source you provided. The problem I understood is with the page load. You are executing some JavaScript functions before all related things loaded.

You should try jquery document ready function

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Put your call inside the ready function.

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside $( window ).on( "load", function() { ... }) will run once the
>   entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

So your code will be something

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
   organizeChartsInTabs();
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks by your answer. I'm doing exactly what you are answering and still not working, very strange!

Comment: are you using cdn js for all